# How do I set "options" parameter in a PostgreSQL connection string?

Tags: postgresql

Using PG 9.5. Towards the bottom of the [libpq-connect documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-connect.html), just before `application_name` is the `options` parameter keyword, which I would like to use to set a specific `work_mem` value.

I'm just not sure how to use this keyword, along with a value. Here is my configuration file:

`dbconnection host=localhost dbname=test user=xxx application_name=test options='work_mem=256MB' password=xxx`

What is the correct syntax? Incidentally, I don't know how to check for `work_mem` value of an active socket. That would also help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading the documentation of the [`options` connection option](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-OPTIONS) and [connection strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) in general, I'd write it like this:

```
dbname=test options='-c work_mem=256MB' application_name=test
```

To get the current setting for a connection, run the following SQL command:

```
SHOW work_mem;
```

Comment: I'll get back to you shortly for the options, but the second part is not what I am looking for. I want to check `work_mem` of a live socket, inside an application for instance, not from within psql or pgadmin. For example I was hoping this information would be provided by `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;` but it's not. IOW, a way to confirm that my application sockets have been raised to 256MB instead of their default value.

Comment: You *can* call `SET` from your application (it is a regular SQL statement), but you can also use the [`current_setting`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET-TABLE) function if you prefer.

Comment: So the `-c` seems to work. As in the application has started. I'm still not sure how I can show from within psql or pgadmin the `work_mem` set by external connections. I will ask through another Stack Overflow post. Thanks!

Comment: There are no easy methods to figure out settings in effect for *another* connection.  The only way I can think of is to attach to the database backend with `gdb` and say `print work_mem`...

Comment: Interesting suggestion! [Here's my follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229810/how-to-show-work-mem-of-external-postgresql-connections).