# How to show WORK_MEM of external PostgreSQL connections?

Tags: postgresql

I know I can use `SHOW WORK_MEM;` in psql to view the value of the connection currently used. But what about other connections? I have an application that opens many connections and dynamically changes the `WORK_MEM` based on context. I would like to monitor these `WORK_MEM` changes to ensure that they are being applied.

In other words I would like to "tweak" `pg_stat_activity` to also include `WORK_MEM` or any other session parameter. I checked `pg_top`, it doesn't include such an option.

Perhaps this EBD post about using a perl extension to [display connection CPU and RAM usage](https://www.enterprisedb.com/monitor-cpu-and-memory-percentage-used-each-process-postgresqlppas-91) could be modified to execute `SHOW WORK_MEM` on every active socket? If so could anyone provide an example?

I'm using 9.5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 in case it matters.

Comment: Are you sure `work_mem` is connection independent? I think is server parameter

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: no, you can change that for your current session.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without hacking Postgres. An additional problem is that `set work_men = ..` is transactional. So you would also need some way of seeing uncommitted changes in other sessions.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza [Here is more information for you](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set.html) (SET -- change a run-time parameter)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Well, I am not using `LOCAL`, and my sockets are opened for a long time, so the value should remain changed for their entire life no?

Comment: @Jeff: if autocommit is turned off, then the following is possible `set work_mem = '1GB'; rollback;` and you are back to the default setting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If I move setting `work_mem` to the connection string, then will it be permanent for the lifetime of the connection and unaffected by a rollback or reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break into the process with a debugger on the operating system level.

I'll show how to do it on Linux:

```
$ psql "dbname=test options='-c work_mem=256MB' application_name=test"
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.

test=>  SELECT pg_backend_pid();
 pg_backend_pid
----------------
          21089
(1 row)
```

Now I can break into the process on the server machine:

```
$ gdb /path/to/postgres-9.6.1/bin/postgres 21089
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-90.el6)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
...
(gdb) print work_mem
$1 = 262144
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /path/to/postgres-9.6.1/bin/postgres, process 21089
(gdb) quit
```

You wouldn't want to do this on a production system, since the backend is blocked while you are debugging it.

Comment: Thanks for the step-by-step. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Works great, saved me a lot of trouble.